# Where can I find a BTX motherboard with an LGA 775 socket?

Tags: motherboard, requirements, upgrade

I have a Dell XPS 410 which has a [Dell P965 BTX motherboard](http://www.anandtech.com/systems/showdoc.aspx?i=2834&p=2). I want to upgrade the motherboard and replace the CPU...but I cannot find any BTX sized motherboards with a 775 socket.

Here's a list of [Intel socket 775 motherboards](http://www.motherboardsdirect.com/index.php?cPath=21_45).

I've searched newegg and a few other places with no luck, where can I find a suitable motherboard?

Also, is it even worth the effort to upgrade just the motherboard & CPU on an older PC, or should I consider getting a bare bones system instead?

---

**Update:** The closest thing I could find is this: http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=D955XCS-PB&cat=MBB

The only problem is the 1066 bus speed. My goal was to upgrade the motherboard so I could run a chip with a 1333 bus speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with Dell: they're using custom-made mainboards, you can't just buy a board somewhere 'off the rails' and fit it into a Dell computer. either you can order a mainboard that fits into the XPS 410 from Dell or you will need a new case and PSU as well.

on another note: Dell computers are pretty solid work horses, but you can only upgrade very little, after that its 'we gladly sell you a shiny new faster computer' and they're certainly no overclocking material. so if you're the experimental type, then Dell is not for you.

Comment: Haha yeah, well now I know. I decided to get a new case: http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/searchtools/item-Details.asp?EdpNo=4959967&sku=B69-9001&srkey=B69-9001

Comment: you might actually SAVE money if you buy all components new and build your own machine and then sell the XPS 410 which is by no means a poor computer and still worth a few quid rather than scraping it for the few parts you may still have use for.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, more research shows the BTX form factor was cancelled.

> However, future development of BTX
>   retail products by Intel was canceled
>   in September 2006. A proprietary form
>   factor is now used by many companies

([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTX_%28form_factor%29))

That's unfortunate, I suppose my only option is to buy a bare bones machine and salvage whatever components I can from the old machine.